# Does anyone have a copy of SGA 4?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

It's not on Laszlo's site, although the latest message says that it is indeed going to be published, that was way back in 2010.

Comment: Is it this? http://www.math.polytechnique.fr/~laszlo/sga4/SGA4-1/sga41.pdf, or all parts http://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/1e177n/does_anyone_have_a_pdf_of_the_texed_version_of/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please see:

http://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/1e177n/does_anyone_have_a_pdf_of_the_texed_version_of/

There are three parts and here are the pdf's:

- http://www.math.polytechnique.fr/~laszlo/sga4/SGA4-1/sga41.pdf
- http://www.math.polytechnique.fr/~laszlo/sga4/SGA4-2/sga42.pdf
- http://www.math.polytechnique.fr/~laszlo/sga4/SGA4-3/sga43.pdf

Answer (score 2):

This old question still comes up in google so I leave the following answer: an independent (?) latex version but also scans of the originals are available here:

http://fabrice.orgogozo.perso.math.cnrs.fr/SGA4/index.html

- [Volume 1](http://www.normalesup.org/%7Eforgogozo/SGA4/tomes/tome1.pdf)
- [Volume 2](http://www.normalesup.org/%7Eforgogozo/SGA4/tomes/tome2.pdf)
- [Volume 3](http://www.normalesup.org/%7Eforgogozo/SGA4/tomes/tome3.pdf)

Comment: Are the Lazlo and Orgogozo retyping projects independent? If yes, what was the reason to start the second one?

Comment: @JonasFrei I can only judge from the outside like you but I doubt they are independent as they contain the litterally same notes de l'éditeur (at least the first two).

Comment: Ahh interesting, so maybe Orgogozo just continued Lazlo's work. So that means probably the Orgogozo version is more up-to-date.